# Using Nested setInterval in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am stuck in a situation where in I need to use nested setintervals.
The situation is that I am processing a call, that needs to be checked after sometime if it has cleared or not.
if not, again I need to wait for same amount of time.
This is working fine till now.

Now I have another call, that I need to finish in between first call. 
My question is how to use the nested setInterval function

Here's existing code:

```
var test = setInterval(function () {
                    if (AllSucceeded) {
                        testWindow.hide();
                        clearInterval(test);

                        if (actionInProgress)
                            return;
                        actionInProgress = true;
                        test1Window.show();
                    }
                }, 200);
```

Here's what I am trying now:

```
var test = setInterval(function() {
            if (AllSucceeded) {
                testWindow.hide();
                clearInterval(test);

                if (actionInProgress)
                    return;
                actionInProgress = true;
                var testFinal = setInterval(function() {
                    if (AllSucceed2) {
                        SomeCode();
                        clearInterval(testFinal);
                    }
                }, 200);
                test1Window.show();
            }
```

}, 200);

What I am trying to achieve here is that the test1 Window should not show before I get AllSucceed2 as success.

Comment: why don't you try using custom event listener?

Comment: Even if this could be made to work it seems like a horrible approach. A custom event, promises, pretty much anything would be cleaner.

Comment: Any example here?